# React Native Trying to search for users, refreshing every time the user types

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to make an auto-refreshing flatlist every time the user types something, like Instagram’s search does. 
The compiler keeps complaining about a missing variable called `search`.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      error: null,
      search: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, search } = this.state;
    const url = `https://pacific-basin-57759.herokuapp.com/api/account/users?page=${page}&search=${search}`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          search: this.state.search
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  handleSearch = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        search: this.state.search
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  }

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({search:text})} />;
  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              //roundAvatar
              title={`${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`}
              subtitle={item.username}
              //avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}`
```

I've looked at the [Fetch API documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and it doesn't really give any useful info (it's all over the place).

Comment: Where does it complain?

Comment: I'm sorry it dosen't but I want to search for users so basically how to re-render the list and have a listener on the textinput and get a new request based on the textinput.

Comment: Create a function onSearchTextChange(text) which makes a new request using text and then saves it as 'search' in your state, and after that pass this function to onChangeText={(text) => this.onSearchTextChange(text)}

Comment: I tried to implement like this

Comment: `  onSearchTextChange = (text) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        search: this.state.search
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  }`

Comment: renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round onChangeText={(text) => this.onSearchTextChange({search:text})} />;
  };

Comment: Still dosent work 